# Webdeploy Publish Profile password saving

Tags: visual-studio

I saved a publish profile into an .xml along wit all the login info.  But when i import this XML to another computer and try to publish, it'll say that my password is incorrect.

What can I do to have the password correctly saved into the publish profile and compatible with other computer?

Comment: Do the computers have the same OS?

Comment: A question on this. As far as I know, the encrypted password gets saved in a ....pubxml.user file besides your ....pubxml file when importing a PublishProfile in VisualStudio (2012). Did you use this one on the other machine, or did you do a separate import of the ....PublishProfile on the other machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the publishing profile to work across different computers, you need to save the password in plain text.

Comment: What is the incantation to do so?

Comment: Maybe using the profile on a build server? At least that's my case. And I came here as my clear text password still isn't recognized by TFS 2015 Build vNext...

Comment: How can you save the password in plain text?

Comment: Plain password can be stored in `Project/PropertyGroup/Password` XML element of .pubxml file (used by VisualStudio). For example this file can be used with `dotnet publish YOURPROJECT.csproj /p:PublishProfile:"YOUR-PROFILE-NAME"`

Comment: But what is the password?! I I never designated a password when I created my profile so I don't know what it is!!!

Comment: OK so the password is in the .PublishSettings file that you download from the Web App in Azure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635783/where-do-i-get-my-actual-azure-website-deployment-password?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that the program purposely obfuscates the passwords using the current PC's "salt" and generates a unique hash. Thus, preventing the passwords from being stolen via the profile publish function.

Comment: I've seen this being done by Azure hosting, where you can simply download the publishing file and you can publish.  The password is in there as well.  So it must be doable, I am just not sure how.

Comment: @user1785999 The file you download from Azure Portal that does contain a password is a `*.PublishSettings` file, whereas a Publishing Profile for Visual Studio is a `*.pubxml` file. They have different schemas. The `*.pubxml` file is actually a valid MSBuild targets file, whereas `PublishSettings` is just a plain-old-XML-file. I do agree the terms "Publish settings file" and "Publishing profile" are too similar which results in this confusion.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by user1785999, you can save the password in plain text, just add the password element to your .pubxml file:

```
    <UserName>YourName</UserName>
    <Password>YourPassword</Password>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I don't think Password is a valid field in the pubxml file.

Comment: Should be `<UserPWD>`

Answer (score 4):

Just to add an additional answer, this may be version specific for .pubxml, but you can add these line to ensure visual studio save the password.

Make sure to use the ".\" prefix for a local account, and "domain\" prefix for an Active Directory account.

```
<UserName>.\PubUser1</UserName>
<UserPWD>Password1234</UserPWD>
<_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
```