# Where do I get my actual Azure Website Deployment password?

Tags: azure, deployment

In Visual studio 2015, when I Publish my Website/Webapp to Azure, I'm able to create a new publishing profile automatically (by entering my personal Azure account credentials), this creates the `.pubxml` and `.pubxml.user` files. The deployment username is of the form "`$websiteName`" and the password is represented by a long series of bullet points. The `.pubxml.user` file contains the actual password, which is encrypted such that only my Visual Studio can read it, by decrypting it with my local Windows user account - I, as a human, have no way to see it. Also, the `.user` files are excluded from Source Control (but the `.pubxml` files are included in Source Control).

When another person on my team tries to deploy the website, they get the same deployment settings, but are prompted for the password for the "`$website`" account. I have no idea where to get this password from - the Azure Management portal does not display it.

If the person opens the portal and chooses to Reset the publishing profile, then they can download a new `.pubxml` file that contains an encrypted password that I understand only their personal Azure credentials can decrypt, but that breaks deployment for me and other users because now their saved passwords (in the `.user` files) is invalidated.

I understand this is a different username+password to the "Deployment Credentials" blade on the Azure portal because currently the website has no Deployment Credentials set, in addition if I were to set one, the username is different. The Portal states that those credentials are for FTP access anyway - no mention is made of the Web Deploy feature.

Comment: Just a silly thought - have you tried using a password unmasking tool on the password textbox in Visual Studio? Something like http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bullets_password_view.html

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can get the current credentials via the Portal or PowerShell/CLI.

### Azure Portal

On the portal, there is a button at the top of the webapp blade to download the publish profile (not the deployment credentials blade, but the main web app blade).

[image: Screenshot of Azure Portal as of April 2019]

### Azure PowerShell

First, ensure the Azure PowerShell cmdlets are installed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.3.0

1. Open an elevated PowerShell window.
2. Enter `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`. Ensure the output shows you have Major version 5 or later. If this command gives you an error then you're running PowerShell v1 which is ancient at this point.
3. Enter `Install-Module -Name AzureRM` (you may be prompted to update NuGet, in which case you should)
4. Wait for it to finish installing.
5. Enter `Import-Module AzureRM`
6. Enter `Connect-AzureRmAccount` and complete the authentication process.
7. Run this command to save the publishing profile to a file on disk (line-breaks added for readability, in reality put this on a single line). Set `$WebAppName` and `$ResourceGroupName` as appropriate:

   ```
   Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile
       -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
       -Name $WebAppName
       -OutputFile creds.xml
       -Format WebDeploy
   ```

### .publishsettings file

The `.publishsettings` file is an XML file (without line-breaks). Inside you'll find a document with this structure. Look for the `userPWD` attribute in the `<publishProfile>` element with `publishMethod="MSDeploy"`. Don't use the FTP credentials (in the second `<publishProfile>` element) because the username is different.

The `userPWD` attribute value is not encrypted, but is the base64 (or base62?) encoding of completely random bytes. You can copy and paste this value directly into the credential prompt within Visual Studio's publishing wizard.

```
<publishData>
    <publishProfile
        profileName="SITE - Web Deploy"
        publishMethod="MSDeploy"
        publishUrl="SITE.scm.azurewebsites.net:443"
        msdeploySite="SITE"
        userName="$SITE"
        userPWD="YOUR PASSWORD IS HERE"                    <-- This attribute here
        destinationAppUrl="http://SITE.azurewebsites.net"
        SQLServerDBConnectionString=""
        mySQLDBConnectionString=""
        hostingProviderForumLink=""
        controlPanelLink=""
        webSystem="WebSites"
    >
        <databases />
    </publishProfile>

    <publishProfile
        profileName="SITE - FTP"
        publishMethod="FTP"
        publishUrl="ftp://SITE.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot"
        ftpPassiveMode="True"
        userName="SITE\$SITE"
        userPWD="FTP PASSWORD IS HERE"
        destinationAppUrl="http://SITE.azurewebsites.net"
        SQLServerDBConnectionString=""
        mySQLDBConnectionString=""
        hostingProviderForumLink=""
        controlPanelLink=""
        webSystem="WebSites"
    >
        <databases />
    </publishProfile>
</publishData>
```

Comment: Sigh.  As usual 'Powershell' evoked without specifying how to get the command.  Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile : The term 'Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: You probably need to install the Azure PowerShell cmdlets... try this: http://aka.ms/webpi-azps -- you'll have to Login-AzureRMAccount first and Select-AzureRMSubscription if you have more than one sub.

Comment: In my case, I logged-on to the Azure Portal and downloaded the Publish Profile from the App Service's blade, and indeed, the unencrypted password is present in the file - I copied and pasted it into VS's publishing wizard and it works fine now without needing to reset anything..

Answer (score 17):

If you are not familiar with PowerShell, you can try the below instruction to get the deployment username and password using the [azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli).

```
az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name your_web_app_name --resource-group your_resource_group
```

[image]

You also add --query to retrieve the "userPWD"

```
az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name your_web_app_name --resource-group your_resource_group --query '[].userPWD' -o tsv
```

Output will be like

oMarhPTTJc6F7muHfz11232342342342342420tv5Lwikf1Xc

Comment: You realize that masking the publish URL but not masking the destination URL in your screenshot doesn't help you?

Comment: @SvenAelterman Thanks for warning me that. I did forget. But it doesn't matter because I've removed this app though.

Comment: What can these creds be used for? I usually don't like to see "userPwd" or the like in log files. Especially those that can be "pasted in the xyz field to do things". Should this file be protected?

Answer (score 5):

I found an easier way to get the deployment credentials in the Azure Portal. In your App Service, go to the *Deployment Center* blade. Check the *Application scope* credentials in the *FTPS Credentials* tab.

[image: Azure App Service Deployment Center]