# Web Publish using publishsettings file on VSTS Release

Tags: azure-devops, web-deployment

Is it possible to configure a [release in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/overview) only using Web Publish method? I want to use it in a shared host, which I do not have permission to use PowerShell, but I already have a [.publishsettings file that I manually use in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx).

[image]

I'm stuck in the step of setting a Deployment Group, since in this shared host is not possible to configure it. ["A deployment group is a collection of machines with a VSTS agent on each of them. Each machine interacts with VSTS to coordinate deployment of your app."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups)

Anyone tried to configure this kind of deploy? Is it possible to accomplish that using commands lines or other kind of configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store the plain password in the secret variable of build/release, then specify the password through MSBuild argument (`/p:Password={variable}`).

After that you can specify the public profile (`.pubxml` file instead of `.publishsettings` file) in **Visual Studio Build** task (e.g. `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="{profile name}"`)

Comment: When I publish from the machine where I saved the password, it works. But when I publish from the VSTS Build, I get "Error ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED: Web deployment task failed.". Do you know if  the password is stored using machine specific info? So the VSTS can't decode the .pubxml.user?

Comment: @mqueirozcorreia Try to specify the password as plain text and check the result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762615/webdeploy-publish-profile-password-saving

Comment: You can store the password in secret variable and replace the pubxml file through [replace token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task

Comment: You helped me a lot, but we need to change the solution in order to help other people looking in this question. 

Do you want to edit your answer? Or do you want to me to create a new answer?

First, it is not possible to use .pubxml.user in VSTS because the password is encrypted. 
The best way to pass the password was through MSBuild argument, so my argument ended as below:
/t:MyProject /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="myprofile.pubxml" /p:Password=$(publishpwd)

where publishpwd was a added variable with my plain password

Comment: @mqueirozcorreia Great! I updated the answer. On the other hand, you can store the plain password in the secret variable of build/release.